# Display error with LinearLayout in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm a begginner in android developping.

I'm trying to display 3 ImageButton in the top, one next to the other horizontally, and after those 3 buttons i want to display a list of items.
The problem is that I obtain the listview on top the 3 buttons, so I m not able to click on the buttons.

Here is my layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.twitter.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp" 
        android:paddingBottom="32dp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/hometimeline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/home" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/mytimeline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/mytimeline" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/posttweet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/plus" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `layout_below` to show listview below the buttons.

> **android:layout_below**: 
>   Positions the top edge of this view below the view specified with a resource ID.

First assign an id to the linearlayout which wraps the 3 buttons.

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" 
    android:paddingBottom="32dp" >
```

Later add layout_below=layout1 to show the listview below the layout.

```
    <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout1"" />
```